# Snap and Run Objective Flickr example - Won't compile?

Tags: ios

Okay, so this seems pretty embarrassing but I downloaded objectiveflickr and opened up the Snap and Run example, entered my API and Secret Key in the SampleAPIKey.h file and get the error:

> error Supply your own Flickr API key and shared secret

Here is a screenshot of the error (Please be aware that's not a real API key or secret, I made it up for illustrative purpose!)

[Error screenshot](http://www.clearfusion.co.uk/images/error.jpg)

I'm not new to iPhone/iPad development but I am completely new to adding this type of option to an app so thought if I could have a look at the example it would help me to figure out the implementation in my own app....the problem is I can't even get the example working which is slightly worrying!!

Comment: Comment out the pragma #error line

Comment: Thanks just the job....although I feel slightly embarrassed!

Answer (score 0):

Once you have filled in your own info for key & secret in the .h file you just comment out the line above that says error

Simple as that.

Also note that the auth URL has to go into the info.plist file, not just in the .h so check out the sample and copy from that.